# Android YouTubeSupportFragment player returning null

Tags: java, android-fragments, this, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been working on a personal Android project related to YouTube based off a demo, however I have ran into an issue that I can't seem to figure out (or understand).

The original code uses a basic `PlayerView` whereas this uses a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`.

The app plays videos just fine as long as `player.cueVideo("VIDEOID")` is inside `onInitializationSuccess`. But will crash with a `NullPointerException` on player variable if placed inside the method `playVideoAtSelection`.

**** The original code had the following line inside onInitializationSuccess, however for me it's telling me that player cannot be resolved. ****

I've never seen `this` used like this before so it has been throwing me off.

```
this.player = player;
```

MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
AutoCompleteTextView atvSearch;
public String thumbnailURL;
public String mediaTitle;
public String videoID;
private TextView autoItem;
private ImageView autoImage;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> resultList;

private static final String KEY_CURRENTLY_SELECTED_ID = "currentlySelectedId";

private YouTubePlayer mPlayer;
private YouTubePlayer player = null;

private ArrayAdapter<ListEntry> videoAdapter;
private Spinner videoChooser;

private MyPlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener;

private int currentlySelectedPosition;
private String currentlySelectedId;

private static final ListEntry[] ENTRIES = {
        new ListEntry("Androidify App", "irH3OSOskcE", false),
        new ListEntry("Chrome Speed Tests", "nCgQDjiotG0", false),
        new ListEntry("Playlist: Google I/O 2012", "PL56D792A831D0C362", true)};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "IN onCreate!");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_playlist, new PlaylistFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    //YouTubePlayerFragment playerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance("irH3OSOskcE");
    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, playerFragment).commit();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            mPlayer = player;
            mPlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
            mPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);

            if (!wasRestored) {
                playVideoAtSelection();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            //error
        }

    });

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_search);
    autoCompView.setAdapter(new QueryAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
    autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    playerStateChangeListener = new MyPlayerStateChangeListener();

    videoChooser = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.video_chooser);

    videoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ListEntry>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ENTRIES);
    videoAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    videoChooser.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    videoChooser.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

}

public void playVideoAtSelection() {
    if (mPlayer == null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "WE DUN GOOFD PLAYER IS NULL... ");
    }
    player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "WE HAVE ENTERED PLAYVIDEOATSELECTION... ");
    /*ListEntry selectedEntry = videoAdapter.getItem(currentlySelectedPosition);
    if (selectedEntry.id != currentlySelectedId && player != null) {
        currentlySelectedId = selectedEntry.id;
        if (selectedEntry.isPlaylist) {
            player.cuePlaylist(selectedEntry.id);
        } else {
            player.cueVideo(selectedEntry.id);
        }
    }*/
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    currentlySelectedPosition = pos;
    playVideoAtSelection();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Do nothing.
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    state.putString(KEY_CURRENTLY_SELECTED_ID, currentlySelectedId);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    currentlySelectedId = state.getString(KEY_CURRENTLY_SELECTED_ID);
}

private final class MyPlayerStateChangeListener implements YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {
    String playerState = "UNINITIALIZED";

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        playerState = "LOADING";
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String videoId) {
        playerState = String.format("LOADED %s", videoId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
        playerState = "AD_STARTED";
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        playerState = "VIDEO_STARTED";
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        playerState = "VIDEO_ENDED";
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason reason) {
        playerState = "ERROR (" + reason + ")";
        if (reason == YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason.UNEXPECTED_SERVICE_DISCONNECTION) {
            // When this error occurs the player is released and can no longer be used.
            player = null;
            //setControlsEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}

private static final class ListEntry {

    public final String title;
    public final String id;
    public final boolean isPlaylist;

    public ListEntry(String title, String videoId, boolean isPlaylist) {
        this.title = title;
        this.id = videoId;
        this.isPlaylist = isPlaylist;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public class QueryAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {


    public QueryAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return resultList.get(index).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        if (row == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_query, parent, false);
        }
        ArrayList<String> text = resultList.get(position);
        String title = text.get(2);
        String url = text.get(1);
        videoID = text.get(0);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "YOOOOOO BAIIII: " + title + url);

        autoItem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
        autoImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail);

        autoItem.setText(title);

        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        autoImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

        return row;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                // Constraint is the input given by the user
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                    resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    int size = resultList.size();
                    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                        //temp = resultList.get(i);
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "YOOOOOO: " + resultList.get(i));
                        thumbnailURL = resultList.get(i).get(1);
                        mediaTitle = resultList.get(i).get(2);
                    }

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "YOOOOOO: " + thumbnailURL + " " + mediaTitle);
                    // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }};
        return filter;
    }
}

private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> autocomplete(String input) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> queries = null;

    // If there's no query, there is nothing to look up
    if (input.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    String songQuery = input;

    // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
    // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
    String queryJsonStr = null;

    String part = "id,snippet";
    String order = "relevance";
    String q = songQuery;
    String type = "video";
    String categoryID = "kind";
    String key = DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY;

    try {
        // Construct the URL for the query
        final String BASE_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?";
        final String PART_PARAM = "part";
        final String ORDER_PARAM = "order";
        final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
        final String TYPE_PARAM = "type";
        final String CATEGORYID_PARAM = "videoCategoryId";
        final String KEY_PARAM = "key";

        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(PART_PARAM, part)
                .appendQueryParameter(ORDER_PARAM, order)
                .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, q)
                .appendQueryParameter(TYPE_PARAM, type)
                .appendQueryParameter(CATEGORYID_PARAM, categoryID)
                .appendQueryParameter(KEY_PARAM, key)
                .build();

        URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "BUILT URI: " + builtUri.toString());
        // Create the request to YouTube, and open the connection
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Read the input stream into a String
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        if (inputStream == null) {
            // Nothing to do.
            return null;
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
            // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
            // buffer for debugging.
            buffer.append(line + "\n");
        }

        if (buffer.length() == 0) {
            // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
            return null;
        }

        queryJsonStr = buffer.toString();

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Query JSON String: " + queryJsonStr);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR ", e);
        // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
        // to parse it.
        return null;

    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
            }
        }
    }

    try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(queryJsonStr);
        QueryJSONParser queryJSONParser = new QueryJSONParser();

        // Getting the parsed data as a list construct
        queries = queryJSONParser.parse(jsonObject);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    }

    return queries;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Relevant XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top">

    <include
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        layout="@layout/player_controls_container" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

LOGCAT:

```
08-08 19:52:23.404    6040-6040/com.android.youtube V/MainActivity﹕ WE DUN GOOFD PLAYER IS NULL...
08-08 19:52:23.404    6040-6040/com.android.youtube D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-08 19:52:23.404    6040-6040/com.android.youtube W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41894da0) 
08-08 19:52:23.414    6040-6040/com.android.youtube E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.youtube, PID: 6040
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.youtube.MainActivity.playVideoAtSelection(MainActivity.java:132)
        at com.android.youtube.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:148)
```

Comment: Do you have error? If so post it here? And do you want to know about "this"?

Comment: Can you tell me, what is at line 132?

Comment: Does the exception occur when you select an item?

Comment: The following logcat messages is when the line player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0"); inside playVideoAtSelection() is uncommented. And yes, how could I implement the line this.player=player; with my code? I understand it references the current object but why am I getting an error when I try to use it?

Comment: @nabin line 132: player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");

Comment: Try to put that line in else statement i.e. only when the player is not null.

Comment: @Nabin and no, the app crashes at launch when line 132 is uncommented. Otherwise, I just recognize that player is equal to null, (from my error messages).

Comment: And do you always get player to be null?

Comment: @Nabin Yes, player is null inside the playVideoAtSelection() method. It is not null inside onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored). How could I pass player appropriately so it is not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting **NullPointerException** because your **player** variable is not initialized. You have commented this line:

```
this.player = player;
```

And for the question what is **this.player = player**?

**this** refers to the **current object**

For example:

```
public class myClass{
   int x;
   public myClass(int x){
   this.x = x;
  }
}
```

In the above example, you have used **this** because, you want to assign value of x to the x(attribute of myClass).

PS: If you are confused with **this** you can easily do the following:

Change your variable name to something else, may be **mPlayer** 
and change 
`this.player = player` to `mPlayer = player;`

**Edited:**
You have declared the YouTubePlayer outside the class. **Move it inside** i.e. Before overriding onCreate(..) method.

**Updated:**
Since the player is not attribute of the class, it won't know what it is. This is similar to not declaring any variable.

Comment: I have tried that previously. When I use "this.player = player", I get the following error: _cannot find symbol variable player_. I have also tried using 'mPlayer = player;' however I still get the same NullPointerException inside playVideoAtSelection() method.

Comment: Did you make YouTubePlayer mPlayer?

Comment: Yes, I tried that but then mPlayer could not be resolved inside playVideoAtSelection() so I defined mPlayer as public variable at the top as well. Is this correct?

Comment: hey move that line after class declaration i.e. just before overriding onCreate() function

Comment: Hmmm.. do you know why it would tell me that the player variable inside this.**player** = player; cannot be resolved? I am certain my problem lies here since this was not an issue when onInitializationSuccess was defined outside of onCreate. It only became a problem when onInitializationSuccess was placed inside onCreate.

Comment: I apologize, that was a typo on my part. YouTubePlayer player had been defined before onCreate. I have also tried moving it inside onCreate with no luck.

Comment: Don't move inside onCreate()

Comment: Did you try doing YouTubePlayer player = null;?

Comment: Yes, still no luck. Could you please explain why it would tell me that the player variable inside this.**player** = player; cannot be resolved? I am certain my problem lies here since the app worked fine when onInitializationSuccess was defined outside of onCreate.

Comment: why are you doing player = player, do this.player = player.

Comment: I would move it back outside, however initializing YouTubePlayerSupportFragments requires it to be initialized inside onCreate.

Comment: You are completely going wrong way. Please post your complete and code and update your question. M not sure where to help you. You are asking different questions. Sometimes about declaration and sometimes about other. Please be stable. And let me see your exact code up to now. thank you

Comment: I did do this.player = player; the player placed inside the asterisks was underlined saying that player could not be resolved.

Comment: Please update your question. Try to put exact code you have got till now. And I can help you further.

Comment: see you have used player instead of mPlayer while calling .cueVideo() method

Comment: Sadly I still get the same error. I left that unchanged since my if (mPlayer == null), kept returning null. Regardless, I tried mPlayer.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0"); and still got the NullPointerException error.

Comment: Yes, you got next error. that is a good sign. You moved further. But nullpointerexcpetion is due to not being initialized. try mPlayer = new YouTubePlayer()

Comment: And plese, if you want help, respond as soon as possible.

Comment: The Android YouTube API docs at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/ includes this note:

    Note: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the API.

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Inside playVideoAtSelection(), I tried mPlayer = new YouTubePlayer(); however it is telling me that YouTubePlayer is abstract and cannot be instantiated. Also, I have the correct version for sure since the player worked when onInitializationSuccess was placed outside of onCreate. You can find the code I based off from here, if it helps. [YouTube Sample GITHUB](https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/blob/master/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/PlayerControlsDemoActivity.java)